# Start at the top of the view gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm making a quiz application. When a team pushed their button i display a view that shows which team pushed their button and the answers of the question. The administrator needs to check each checkbox the team answered. An appropriate score will be calculated in the code and given to the team.

The problem is that when I display the view,  the text (consisting out of JLabels) isn't displayed at the top side of the view. They are more centered. See image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/up7wa.jpg // Image

Here is my code:

```
public class GiveScoreView extends JFrame implements View {
Observable $model;
Controller $controller;

private Question $question; /* Saves the question that is passed by the update */

/*GUI elements */
ArrayList<JLabel> $answerLabels;
ArrayList<JCheckBox> $checkBoxes;
JLabel $questionLabel;
JLabel $teamPressedLabel;

public GiveScoreView(Observable model, Controller controller) {

    setModel(model);
    setController(controller);

    $answerLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    $checkBoxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    $questionLabel = new JLabel();

    $teamPressedLabel = new JLabel();

    initializeFrame();
}

/**
 * Initializes the frame
 */
private void initializeFrame() {
    setTitle("Give a score to the teams"); /* TODO languagebundle, Change the title of the frame */

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); /* Set the layout to gridbaglayout */

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });

    pack();
    setVisible(false); /* Don't display it on default */

}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    $question = (Question) arg1;

    /* Now we need to display this frame */
    if(((QuizModel) getModel()).getDisplayScoreView()){
        $teamPressedLabel.setText("Team " + Integer.toString(((QuizModel) getModel()).getTeamPressed()) + " pushed their button!"); /* TODO messagebundle */
        $teamPressedLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 34)); /* Change the font */
        displayScoreView();
        setVisible(true); /* Now display the JFrame */
    }
}


private void displayScoreView() {
    Multipleanswer multipleanswerQuestion; /* a multiple answer question to display the multipleanswer questions */
    Multiplechoice multiplechoiceQuestion; /* a multiple choice question to display the multiplechoice questions */
    ArrayList<String> answers = null;

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    /* Set the position of the JFrame so it's centered */
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    // Determine the new location of the window
    int w = getSize().width;
    int h = getSize().height;
    int x = (dim.width - w) / 2;
    int y = (dim.height - h) / 2;

    // Move the window
    setLocation(x - 150, y - 150);

    /* Set size */
    setSize(550, 300);


    /* If the question isn't empty */
    if (!($question == null)) {
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;


        $questionLabel.setText($question.getQuestion()); /* Set the text of the JLabel to the question itself */
        $questionLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 26)); /* Change the font */

        add($teamPressedLabel,c); /* Add the label to the JFrame, the team that has pressed it's button */

        /* Display the question under the team pressed text */
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;

        add($questionLabel,c); /* Add the label to the JFrame, the question itself */

        /* If the type of the question is multipleanswer */
        if ($question.getType() == QuestionType.MULTIPLEANSWER) {

            /* Cast it to multipleanswer question */
            multipleanswerQuestion = (Multipleanswer) $question;

            /* Get the answers */
            answers = multipleanswerQuestion.getAnswers();
        } else if ($question.getType() == QuestionType.MULTIPLECHOICE) {

            /* Cast it to multiplechoice question */
            multiplechoiceQuestion = (Multiplechoice) $question;

            /* Get the answers */
            answers = multiplechoiceQuestion.getAnswers();
        }

        /* Speed questions don't show answers so we only display answers if it's not a speed question */
        if ($question.getType() != QuestionType.SPEED) {
            /* Make a JLabel and JCheckBox for each answer */
            for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
                $answerLabels.add(new JLabel(answers.get(i))); /* Make a new JLabel with answer string as text */
                $checkBoxes.add(new JCheckBox()); /* Make a new JCheckBox */

                $answerLabels.get(i).setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
                c.gridx = 0;
                c.gridy = i + 2;
                add($answerLabels.get(i),c); /* Add the label to the JFrame */
                c.gridx = 1;
                c.gridy = i + 2;
                add($checkBoxes.get(i),c); /* Add the checkbox to the JFrame */

            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Solution:
Place `weighty = 1;` right after `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;`.

Comment: which labels are not showing right?

Comment: The $questionLabel and the $teamPressedLabel. I would like them higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply a non-zero `weighty` to the components in the bottom row. By default, when all components have zero weights, any spare space is placed around the outside of the whole layout, giving the effect you see. By applying non-zero weights you tell the layout engine to put the spare space inside cells of the grid rather than around the outside.

Your current grid is effectively

[image: current grid]

whereas what you need is

[image: grid with weighty=1 on the bottom row]

which you can achieve by setting `weighty` to 1.0 and `anchor` to `NORTHWEST` for just the last row of components.

Comment: Can you say which label(s)? I don't know what you mean with "bottom row". Thanks EDIT : i did put it in front of everything and it displayed quite nicely now. Thanks.

Comment: @user3485470 Please accept this answer (click the tick shape next to it) rather than editing a tag into your question title.